# conditional statement checking if node js filesystem.writefile is a success

Tags: node.js, express, writefile

Can it be said that fs promise writeFile and fs writeFileSync are the same thing? or rather, would behave the same way?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fsProm = require ('fs').promises

//write file sync
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, data)

write file promise

fsProm.writeFile(filePath, data)
```

can any one please explain?

Also, fs promises writefile returns a promise, how do you check if the write was a success, and write a conditional statement based on that?

```
if (fsProm.writeFile === undefined) {
 //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

how do i check if the operation was a success, and write a conditional statement based on that??

Answer (score 0):

> Can it be said that fs promise writeFile and fs writeFileSync are the same thing? or rather, would behave the same way?

`fs.writeFileSync` *blocks* the process. So in that way, they don't behave the same way.

> Also, fs promises writefile returns a promise, how do you check if the write was a success, and write a conditional statement based on that?

```
try {
  await fsProm.writeFile(filePath, data);
  //do something
} catch (err) {
  //do something else
}
```

Finally, this is the most current recommendation for importing fs/promises:

```
// If you're using CommonJS
const fsPromises = require('node:fs/promises');

// If you're using ESM
import * as fsPromises from 'node:fs/promises';
```

Comment: well, actually, in my code, i m trying to use nodemailer to send the written data to an email address, if you don't mind, how could i combine both using the try-catch method?

Comment: @payiyke open a new question.